# MVC 3 URL routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, url-routing

I've just started working on MVC 3 and i want to create a url like 'http://server/news/9635/demo-news-title' but i don't know how can i map routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "news",
                "{controller}/{id}/{title}",
                new { controller = "news", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

i tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working. What should i do?

Thanks

Comment: What is 'not working'? are you getting an exception? finding the wrong controller? what specifically isn't happening that you expect to be?

Comment: well when i wrote '/news/221/demo-title' to the browser i got a "Server Error in / Application" error. Is the mapRoute method good for the url i wrote above?

Comment: can you show us your controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your route is right, but you have to put your route before default route . This is example :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "news",
                "{controller}/{id}/{title}",
                new { controller = "news", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

You provided no information about what you mean with "not working".
To check if your route is the problem you can use [Phil Haacks's ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Comment: well i thing i solve the problem, i got 2 maproutes, one for default and one for the news, so i changed the order of them and now it seems working...

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "news",
            "news/{id}/{title}",
            new { controller = "news", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```